# What is the picture for $S^1\times S^2$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let **M** be a compact, connected, two-dimensional manifold such that $M = S^1\times S^2$.

How should one picture **M**?

The following is from Abraham and Marsden, Foundations of Mechanics:

> Let $M$ be a compact, connected, two-dimensional manifold, $X\in\mathscr X(M)$ and $A$ a minimal set of $X$.  Then either (i) A is a critical point, (ii) A is a closed orbit, (iii) $A=M$ and $M=S^1\times S^2$.

Comment: I like to think of it as a thickened sphere with the inner and outer boundaries glued together.

Comment: What do $S1$ and $S2$ denote?

Comment: @StefanH: I assume $S^1$ and $S^2$.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: But $M$ isn't two-dimensional then

Comment: What is $\mathscr X(M)$? Is it the vector fields of $M$?

Comment: @StefanH: Ah, I didn't see that it said $2$ dimensional. I wonder if that's a mistake.

Comment: The easiest way is probably via its universal cover which is $\mathbb{R}\times S^2$. This is easier to visualise if you look at the homeomorphic space $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$. You can then view $M$ as a quotient of this space by the covering action. A fundamental domain of this covering looks like the thickened sphere before gluing the boundaries as described by @GrumpyParsnip.